# add entries to Startup Applications using a post-install script

Tags: scripts, automation, startup-applications

I'm gathering commands to build a post-installation script, and I want to have the script automagically add certain apps to the Startup Applications list as if I had added them manually, such as the GNOME Login sound, and Xscreensaver.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything with post-install scripts for this. You simply need to provide the correct .desktop file for your app, following the [Freedesktop Autostart Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html). This will enable autostart of the app.

Comment: Well, is there any way to make the script generate a .desktop file for each app that I want to autostart?

Comment: Figured it out...I copied the code from an existing .desktop file and modified it for each app I wanted to add, using echo to create the .desktop files from within the script...I can't believe the answer was so simple.